Powershell GUI, GIF and Runspaces
I currently have a GUi that works with a zip file, that contains a few thousand .zip files of .csv data
My script currently works correctly, but im looking to add a gif that is displayed while the job is running.
When the job is running the gif will freeze, and the only way i have found (by googling) is to display the gif file in a seperate runspace, seen in the code below.
However the GIF is displayed all the time, and im looking to have the gif closed after the job has completed.
If possible, I would like all controls added to the single form so the manipulation of the images can be controlled.
I have spent a few days looking into this, but i am no further forward, If anyone here can help please
$YEETpictureBox.FlatStyle
$YEETpictureBox.Visible = $true
$YEETpictureBox.add_MouseHover($ShowHelp)
$YEETpictureBox.add_Click({
    $saveGAZ = Save-Gaz
    $ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
    $MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Question
    $MessageBody = "Are you sure you want to extract all files`n`nFrom: $Script:Gazfile`n`nTo: $($saveGAZ)"
    $MessageTitle = 'Selected Connections'
    $Result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody, $MessageTitle, $ButtonType, $MessageIcon)

    switch ($Result) {
        'Yes' {
            # Create runspace
            $runspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
            $runspace.Open()
            # Add script and run asynchronously
            $runspace.CreatePipeline{
                Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
                $image = [Drawing.Bitmap]'C:\path2file\spaceman.gif'
                $pictureBox = [Windows.Forms.PictureBox]@{
                    Dock  = 'Fill'
                    Image = $image
                    Size  = '99,97'
                }
                $form = [Windows.Forms.Form]@{
                    Size            = '99,95'
                    FormBorderStyle = 'None'
                    Owner           = $ApplicationForm
                    StartPosition   = 'CenterParent'
                }
                $form.Controls.Add($pictureBox)
                $form.ShowDialog()
            }.InvokeAsync()

            Start-Job -Name 'Gaz Extraction' -ScriptBlock {
                ShowBalloonTipInfo -Text 'Gazetteer Extraction Started...' -Title 'Gazetteer' -Icon None
                Expand-Archive $using:Script:Gazfile -DestinationPath C:\programdata\ArchiveDetective\GazTEMP -ErrorAction Stop -Force
                Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\programdata\ArchiveDetective\GazTEMP' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
                    Expand-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath (-join $using:saveGAZ + '\CSV') -Force
                    Remove-Item $_.FullName
                }
            } -InitializationScript $initscript
            $YEETpictureBox.Visible = $false
            ShowBalloonTipInfo -Text "Gazetteer Extraction Completed`n`n$($saveGAZ)" -Title 'Gazetteer' -Icon None
        }
    }
})
$ApplicationForm.Controls.Add($YEETpictureBox)


do you need the gif as a secondary form, why not make the PictureBox control visible in the main form on click event? that's gonna make things easier

I had tried that, but when running in a seperate runspce i couldnt call it or set an image
Odd, but i have ran the script now and works similar to how i want it :@
